# C# ASP.NET - Checking ImageUrl and adding class

Tags: c#

Peter here and I'm extra new to coding. What I'm attempting to do is check the actual image url and based on that, change the class. My current code is as so:

```
DataSet ds = cbb.getBannerModule(Convert.ToInt32(MyBannerID));
    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton();
    ib.ImageUrl =  ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Banner_path"].ToString();
    string URL = ib.ImageUrl;
    ib.Width = Unit.Pixel(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Banner_width"].ToString()));
    ib.Height = Unit.Pixel(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Banner_hight"].ToString()));
    ib.PostBackUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Banner_link"].ToString();
    string img1 = "~/admin/IMAGE/Banner/1.jpg";
    string img2 = "~/admin/IMAGE/Banner/2.jpg";
    string img3 = "~/admin/IMAGE/Banner/3.jpg";
    if (URL == img1)
    {
        ban1.Attributes["class"] = "add 1";
    }
    else if (URL == img2)
    {
        ban1.Attributes["class"] = "add 2";
    }
    else if (URL == img3)
    {
        ban1.Attributes["class"] = "add 3";
    }
    else
    {
        ban1.Attributes["class"] = "add 4";
    }
    ban1.Controls.Add(ib);
```

The goal? Change the class to attempt and set a new picture for the hover feature. This is a system created by an outside vendor and the id and class are set inside the ascx file. They set it class="add" but I want to add another class so that when you rollover the image it changes the image. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes name need to be in a single word. You cannot have "add 1" as a single name. Space is to separate multiple class for a single Dom object.

If you want, you can change too "add1" instead of "add 1" and so on. This will set the class to your image to "add1" instead of "add" and "1".

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tip Patrick. I do have another issue after incorporating what you suggested, it looks like my code isn't finding the appropriate paths of the images and checking against the strings I've set? Is there a reason to this? All of images are now being set to only add4 since it is the last condition. Again, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Great if it worked. If so, you need to check the check at the left of the post to specify that this question has been resolved. This way, you help other people in the future to figure out how to solve their question that may look like yours.

Comment: Concerning the string comparison, you will need to use a BreakPoint to debug and see what is the value of the variable URL. Have a nice day.

Comment: Alright, well sounds good, thanks for the tips and instructions

Comment: Hey Patrick, sorry to bother you again, but found out that the variable is returning an imagepath with \'s and not /'s. When I attempted to make the string compare \'s it gave me an error for unrecognized escape sequences, since it is in a string. Any ideas on how I would attempt to compare then? Should I rewrite the URL with /'s?

Comment: Can you give me an example please.

Comment: My apologies, I ended up using string ex = @"\admin\IMAGE"; so that it doesn't attempt to recognize the backslash as an escape sequence. this way I can compare to the URL var. thanks a bunch again!